# Tooltip doesn't display on highchart graph

Tags: highcharts, tooltip

I am using highchart.js to display graph of check-in time and check-out time of employee in a month.

- X-axis will be the day of month.
- Y-axis is the hour-time of the day.

I want to customize the tooltip to be like

```
Check In
5 Aug: 09:40 am
```

or

```
 Check Out
 5 Aug: 09:40 am
```

For some weird reason, it only display the default format x and y. 
The code is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/BFnL9/1/

Is there any bug here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tooltip definition is fine, but it is in the wrong place. Try putting it at the same level as plotOptions instead of inside.

```
      tooltip: {
        crosshairs: true,
         formatter: function(){
           // THIS FUNCTION DOESNT RUN ??????????
           return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
           Highcharts.dateFormat('%e %b', this.x) +': '+ Highcharts.dateFormat('%H %M', this.y) ;
         }

        // headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
        // pointFormat: 'Day {point.x},  Time: {point.y}'
      },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JpMnF/

Comment: Indeed, formatter is supported only on tooltip level, not series. [These options](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.tooltip) are supported by `plotOptions.series.tooltip`.